# Long term screw terminal power

Tags: pi-3, power, power-supply

Okay so I have a PCA9685 hooked up to a raspberry pi 3 so that it can control multiple servos via a c++ program. Currently, I have them hooked up to a battery pack that has red and black wires as gnd and v+. I plan to run this 24/7 for an unknown amount of time. Obviously, batteries tend to eventually drain after prolonged use. I have tried finding a power supply that goes from the wall or a usb to the red and black wires so that I can power my servos. Does anyone know if I can transform a micro-usb cable to accomplish the same task? If not, are there any places where I can buy something that accomplishes the aforementioned task? Thanks.